# Anylogic: How to keep an agent waiting in queue until it changes state? (Discrete Events flowchart)

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I'm starting to use Anylogic for a simulation class, and for this I need to model the following behaviour: there's a stream of agents that enter a FIFO queue, and then enter into a server (that I modeled with a delay block), one at a time. The agents have two states (call them A and B), and if an agent reaches the end of the queue in state A, it has to wait until it returns to state B to go into the service.

I think a wait block with capacity for one agent, between the queue and the delay block could potentially solve this situation. But I don't know how to make the wait block to free the agent as soon as it changes state.

Other methods are welcome. I just need the agent to be retained before the delay block as long as it is in the state A, but not any longer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes... a wait block with capacity 1 after your queue block is what I would do.

Now when your agent enters the state, on the entry action of that stateB you do the following:

```
if(currentBlock().equals(main.waitBlock) && main.service.size()==0){
    main.waitBlock.free(this); 
}
```

You will also need to do this in the "on enter" of the wait block:

```
if(agent.inState(agent.stateB) && service.size()==0){
    self.free(agent);
}
```

also, just in case, add a population of 0 of your agent type in main, to be able to use main. in your agent state code.