# Anylogic: Code generated from graphical interface throws type casting exceptions

Tags: java, anylogic, codegen

After following the advice given in the answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58618511/8076041) question, I ended up with a model with:

- An empty population of agents in main
- A statechart in said agent type that references main (made possible by the previous point)
- A discrete event flowchart, that references the state of the agents

But after building the model, 3 type and casting errors have appeared, and they are in autogenerated code. I don't understand what functionality is provided by said code.

For context, my model is called "Trenes", and my agent type is "Train". All the errors happen inside the `Train` java file.
The exceptions happen in the following snippets:

first one:

```java
  // User API -----------------------------------------------------
  public Main get_Main() {
    {
      Agent owner = getOwner();
      if ( owner instanceof Main ) return (Main) owner;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

This one causes `Cannot cast from Agent to Main`, thanks to the casting `(Main) owner`. It also causes `Incompatible conditional operand types Agent and Main.` because of `owner instanceof Main`.

second one:

```java
  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  private void setupReferences_xjal() {
    main = get_Main();
  }
```

This one calls the method from the first snippet and causes a `Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main to trenes.Main.` in the line `main = get_Main();`

I'd be grateful if someone could guide me about what kind of graphical interface configurations could result in these errors, and how could I correct it without undoing my work with the statechart that references main.

Editing to add captures of the structure of my model and the relevant logic:

- Agent type

  - [The train agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ztgB.png)
  - [Logic of the crewed state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U0bv.png)
  - [Logic of the uncrewed state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6uqt.png)
  - [Logic of the 'hogging' transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5Jew.png)
  - [Logic of the 'crew arrival' transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAOVw.png)
- Discrete events flowchart

  - [The full flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbDQT.png)
  - [Logic of the wait block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuwAT.png)
  - [Logic of the delay block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaB1L.png)

Comment: show the flowchart, your statechart (and where both are located) and the code you used in both and where you use it.

Comment: Thanks @Felipe, I already added captures of the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have messed up some internal coding, this can happen in rare cases.

Try this:

- Create a completely new class `TrainNew`
- embedd it on Main as an agent population
- bit by bit "move over" your functionality (state charts, functions, variables) from `Train` to `TrainNew`
- delete `Train` entirely and resolve any final conflicts (by pointing to `TrainNew`